# 0001: Loop, Asking question until valid response

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I require assistance with a bit of code, I'm practicing with something basic, I'm starting to understand concepts now but I still need much help, I've started with a random number generator and I'd like for it to allow you to guess again until correct.

```
import random

hidden = random.randrange(1, 201)
print(hidden)

guess = int(input("Please enter your guess:"))

if guess == hidden:
    print("Hit!")
elif guess < hidden:
    print("Your guess is too low")
else:
    print("Your guess is too high")
```

*Thanks,
R*

Comment: put the code in a `while True` loop (above your `guess =` line) and add a `break` statement underneath `print("Hit!")`.

Comment: Does this help [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, much appreciated.